# Sending push notifications to your bowser using web sockets & AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, websocket, push-notification

I'm looking at implementing a web app push notifications using web sockets while working with AngularJS. I have researched many examples but have not been able to set up the push notification functionality so far. I have always been shown a message that the connection could not be made.

Could anyone point me in the right direction with a few examples I could refer to? That would be just great!

Thanks!

-Jalesh

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to answer your question without more details.  Check out the SignalR or Socket.IO libraries.  You might also consider the [Angular Socket IO Seed Project](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io-seed)